# Marginal PDF of a function of two variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am working on this problem:

> Suppose that either of two instruments might be used for making a certain measurement.
>   Instrument 1 yields a measurement whose pdf h1 is: **h_1(x) = 2x, for 0 < x < 1**.
>   Instrument 2 yields a measurement whose pdf h2 is: **h_2(x) = 4x^3, for 0 < x < 1**.
>   Suppose that one of the two instruments is chosen at random and a measurement **X** is made with it.
>   Determine the marginal pdf of **X**.

My intuition of the problem is that the pdf would be **f(x) = (1/2)(2x + 4x^3)**, since each instrument has a probability of being used of **0.5**. However, I really can't figure out how to work through it. Would each of **h_1** and **h_2** be a random variable, and **X** a uniform discrete distribution of the two? I'm also confused that it asks for the *marginal* pdf of **X**. Isn't a marginal pdf only applicable to a multivariate distribution? It appears to me that once the two functions were properly combined it would already be univariate... Can someone please help me understand this problem more clearly? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed correct.

They call $f_X(x)$ the marginal probability density of $X$, because there is another variable: Let us call it $N$, the unbiased choice of instrument.  $$N\sim\mathcal U\{1,2\}$$

The Law of Total Probability applied to conditional probability density functions sais that the marginal density function of $X$ is the sum of the joint mixed density/mass functions, as enumerated by $N$ (since $N$ is a discrete r.v.).   So:

$$f_X(x) = f_{X\mid N}(x\mid 1)~\mathsf P(N=1)+f_{X\mid N}(x\mid 2)~\mathsf P(N=2)$$

In this case, you have identified $f_{X\mid N}(x\mid 1)$, the conditional probability function for the measure of the instrument *when given* we choose flute 1, as being equal to $h_1(x)$.   Likewise the other.   Then as the probability of which instrument is selected is unbiased:

$$f_X(x) = \tfrac 12 (h_1(x)+h_2(x))$$

That is okay.